# Using data from Firestore outside of onSuccess

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

I have some data in my Firestore database and I had like to use it.

```
MyData.get().addOnSuccessListener( new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
        if (documentSnapshot.exists()){
            Map<String, Object> MyData = documentSnapshot.getData();
        }else {
            Toast.makeText( MyActivity.this,"no document",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
        }
    }
} ).addOnFailureListener( new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText( MyActivity.this,"error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
    }
} );
```

Now, I had like to use MyData from outside of this listener.

I had like to send this data into some classes I have made to populate a list.

How can I do it?

Thank you

Comment: Take a look into Subjects from RxJava library. They makes possible such kind of messaging

Comment: I would not advise using Rx, before understanding of the basicdata communication, lambdas, listeners etc

Comment: Please check the duplicate to see why do you have this behaviour and how can you solve this using a custom callback.